# F# tuple of Option.None evaluates as tuple of null values

Tags: .net, f#

Can someone tell me why this F# expression:

```
(Option<int*int>.None, Option<int*int>.None)
```

evaluates to

```
val it : (int * int) option * (int * int) option = (null, null)
```

while

```
(Option<int*int>.None
```

simply evaluates to

```
val it : (int * int) option = None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which part of it is surprising, the fact that it's `(null, null)` rather than `(None, None)`?

This is just an artifact of how printing `None` values works. Try `fst it` and you'll see that it's still a proper Option value.

You see this because `None` values are compiled to nulls for performance reasons, even if this is (mostly) transparent when using them within F#. You can get the same behaviour in your types by marking the type with [`UseNullAsTrueValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370528.aspx) compilation flag.